# How to pass data from HTML to PHP without a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I'm working with an api that requires specific ID numbers to retrieve certain objects. Right now I have a form for the user to manually enter an ID and on submission it GETs an object. But what I want is to have links to all the IDs instead so the user can just click and choose which object to retrieve. I'm not necessarily trying to make a GET request from the user click. I can make the GET request on the backend but I just need a way to determine which ID the user is trying to select. I have been searching and searching for a way to do this but I haven't found anything specific to my dilemma. I've read on having a hidden form or using AJAX but is there not a simpler solution?
Is there not a way to where the PHP server can detect which link and ID is clicked to store it in a variable?

For example:

`$lib->request('$ID.'/videos','GET');`

retrieves a set of videos.

`<button type ="button" id="23456" >Video Number 1</button>` 
Is there a way that I could pass the id of the button above to php?

I'm really confused and I'm wondering if I'm over complicating this.

Comment: If you use ajax you can reuse the same id for all requests, the issue you're having is the page gets refreshed.

Comment: Ok so I rephrased the question. I'm not trying to make a get request upon a user click. What I want is to simply have a way to communicate to the server which link the user clicked so that I can send the get request accordingly on the back-end.

Comment: That dont make sense, your saying you want to know which link the user clicked but not making a request, then its not a link.. You also say `I just need a way to determine which ID the user is trying to select`.. links are not selects. Are you talking about like API documentation? Where a user has an "id" and then the calls to the server uses the id without the user supplying an id to pull in the results of a call? If not can you put your question in some example code?

Comment: I rephrased the question again. Sorry if my question is confusing. I hope I explained it better.

Comment: I get ya now, you need to use javascript for setting the users "id" choice (button) and then on your "backend" request/link use the id which was set and then send it.

Comment: Could you give me an example ? It would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can post data with **XHR**!

**Here is a simple example using jQuery to post data**

```
// URL,parameter,callback function,RT datatype
// just one example
$.post("/"+id+"/videos",{},
  function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  "text");//return datatype：json,html,xml,text
}
```

edited

you can get id by event

**need to know**:

*only typeof ID === number triggered*

```
$(document.body).on("mouseup",function(e){
    var _e  = e.target;
    if(typeof _e.id !== "undefined" && !isNaN(+_e.id)){
         var id = _e.id;
         //trigger XHR last edited code
    }
})
```

edited2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="123456" class="id-select">Video Number 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="654321" class="id-select">Video Number 2</button><br>
        <script src="path/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $(document.body).on("mouseup",function(e){
                    var _e  = e.target;
                    if(typeof _e.id !== "undefined" && !isNaN(+_e.id)){
                        var id = _e.id;  //this id is you click button
                        //trigger XHR last edited code

                        /*
                         *   @parma1 url
                         *   @parma2 post parama
                         *   @parma3 callback function
                         *   @parma4 set return datatype
                         */
                        $.post("/"+id+"/videos",{},
                            function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }, "text");//return datatype：json,html,xml,text
                     }
                 }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite I always give you jquery code, but you can't understand, here gives you samples completely

Comment: thank you. I upvoted you but someone else downvoted.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite first floor's answer maybe works well, but you have to leave your HTML page, you can not click another button, you need to redirect back to click again.

Comment: Yes, this is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript for setting the users "id" choice (button) and then pass that id to your "backend" request/link once your ready.

**Here is a simple example using jQuery:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" data-id="123456" class="id-select">Video Number 1</button>
        <button type="button" data-id="654321" class="id-select">Video Number 2</button><br>

        <br>
        <button type="button" class="watch-video">Watch Video</button>

        <br>

        <div id="selected"></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var id = 0;
                $('#selected').html('You not selected the id yet.');

                $('.id-select').click(function(){
                    id = $(this).data('id');
                    $('#selected').html('Selected video id: '+id);
                });

                $('.watch-video').click(function() {
                    window.location.href = '/'+id+'/videos';
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```